# ¿Como asignar un nuevo valor a un array en una sesion?

Tags: php

Verán, estoy tratando de hacer mi sistema para el carrito de una tienda online.
Quiero que cuando el usuario vuelva a agregar el mismo producto la cantidad cambie de 1 a 2 y así sucesivamente.

El problema es que no logro hacer que esta cantidad cambie. En código que dejo, es lo que he intentado, tuve éxito al comprobar si el pruducto ya fue seleccionado pero fallo al actualizar la cantidad

```html
<?php
  //valores que recibo de los inputs
    $id = $_GET['id_car'];
    $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
    $foto = $_GET['foto'];
    $precio = $_GET['precio'];
  //cantidad por defecto es 1
    $cantidad = 1;
    // si no existe la session SHOP la creo y le asigno el primer producto
    if (!isset($_SESSION['SHOP'])) {
        
        $p_seleccionados = array(
            'id' =>  $id,
            'nombre' => $nombre,
            'foto' => $foto,
            'precio' => $precio,
            'cantidad' => $cantidad
        );
        $_SESSION['SHOP'][0] = $p_seleccionados;
        
// aqui agrego el id de los productos para luego comprobar que no se dupliquen
        $_SESSION['PRODUCTOS'][0] = $id;
        
    } else {
        $num_sel = count($_SESSION['SHOP']);
        $coun_p = count($_SESSION['PRODUCTOS']);
//compruebo que no exista el id que acabo de seleccionar en array-session PRODUCTOS
        if (!in_array($id, $_SESSION['PRODUCTOS'])) {
            $_SESSION['PRODUCTOS'][$coun_p] = $productos;
            $p_seleccionados = array(
                'id' =>  $id,
                'nombre' => $nombre,
                'foto' => $foto,
                'precio' => $precio,
                'cantidad' => $cantidad
            );

            $_SESSION['SHOP'][$num_sel] = $p_seleccionados;
            $_SESSION['PRODUCTOS'][$coun_p] = $id;
        } else {
 // esto se ejecuta si el usuario ha seleccionado un producto que ya selecciono anteriormente el problema es que la cantidad no se actualiza
            foreach ($_SESSION['SHOP'] as $indice=>$producto) {
                if ($producto['id'] == $id) {
                    $cantidad =+ 1;
                    $producto['cantidad'] = $cantidad;
                }
            }
           
        }
        print_r($_SESSION['SHOP']);
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto pasa porque el foreach por default no pasa por referencia, es decir en lugar de tomar el array original, crea una copia y sobre esa itera, si quieres que itere sobre el valor por referencia, deberás anteponer un `&` como lo marca la [Documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
  foreach ($_SESSION['SHOP'] as $indice=> &$producto) { //se agrega & para que sea por referencia
            if ($producto['id'] == $id) {
                $cantidad =+ 1;
                $producto['cantidad'] = $cantidad;
            }
        }

    }
    print_r($_SESSION['SHOP']);
```